# FormatException thrown when mapping lucene index to Int32

Tags: c#, lucene, sitecore

I'm using Sitecore's LINQ interface for querying lucene indexes and have created a class derived from SearchResultItem in the usual way with [IndexField] attribute to map a computed index to an Int32 property.

When calling query.GetResults() a FormatException is thrown. After much debugging I have discovered that the string value that causes the format exception is `" \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"`

As I am using a computed index that always returns a valid integer I am at a loss as to explain where that string value is coming from.

What could be causing this?

**edit**

As requested here is the index configuration for the field:

```
<field fieldName="playersquadnumber"                  >BusinessLogicLayer.ComputedIndexFields.PlayerSquadNumber,BusinessLogicLayer</field>
```

and

```
<field fieldName="playersquadnumber"        storageType="YES"  indexType="TOKENIZED"   vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.Int32" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
```

Comment: are you returning null when your string is empty or string.Empty?  Or when an exception is thrown ?

Comment: The code returns null if the IIndexable passed into the ComputeFieldValue method isn't a SitecoreIndexableItem but I've already re-built the indexes with a debugger attached and that code path is never executed.

Comment: Could you include the configuration of your computed index field in the question?

Comment: Have you tried setting the indexType to be UNTOKENIZED?

Comment: Can you check with Luke what the value in the index itself is? (I assume that after your debug session you know which record is causing the exception)

Comment: @Gatogordo Actually, I have no idea which record is causing the exception. I got the value that was causing the exception by switching back to the stack frame for ParseLong in Lucene.Net.Search.AnonymousClassLongParser and looking at the defined locals.

Comment: Can you try mapping your field to a string, just to see the results? Maybe this will get you the 'bad' record so you can proceed the check in Luke.